# Ode containing triangle trigonometry

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, math-history

What has the homogeneous differential equation
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{x^2+3 y^2}{2 x y}$$

its solution written on blackboard ( Germany, 1894 )

$$ x^2 +y^2 - C x^3 = 0 $$

to do with Area of the triangle using Sine or Cosine Rule in Trigonometry ?

$$ Area = \frac {c^2 \sin A \sin B}{2\sin C}$$

What do $(x,y)$ of that equation represent in the curve below $ (C=1)?$

[image]

[NatGeo video 2 min 32 sec onwards](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZyYqyYAKGC0)

Comment: I shall follow this question. Bizarre, isn't it ?

Comment: Yup. Hope you would enjoy it.

Comment: $dx=2y d\varphi$, but I don't see how it is connected with area.

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2308674

Comment: A bit of context to avoid to visiting YouTube: In the clip (from National Geographic's 2017 series "Genius", about Albert Einstein), a young Einstein shows that he's been paying (enough) attention during a math lecture by effortlessly solving the diff eqn, which had been posed by the professor while Einstein was seemingly lost in thought. ... To the question at hand: The prof prefaced the eqn by having his students recall/recite the Laws of Cosines and Sines. This suggests the trig connection, but the exact connection isn't clear. (The professor's words had become distant for dramatic effect.)

Comment: Reputed channel National Geographic had 45 secs for an episode like this...must have been after due factual researches.